# How to write a inner join in parse javascript with Pointer

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have two classes one is **_User** and another is **Vehicle**. In _User Class there is a field named "Location"(GeoPoint), and in Vehicle there is a column named "assignTo"(pointer, points to _User Class's ObjectId). Now I want to get fetch User within 10 Km along with his vehicle details.

**Note**- **_User** and **Vehicle** has one to one relationship.And Vehicle's Class column **AssignTo** (pointer) Points to _User's class **ObjectId**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
//var currentLocation
var q_u = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
q_u.near("Location", currentLocation);
q_u.withinKilometers(10);
//inner query is a short cut to get ids, and fetch the next one
//but the query max limit is 1000, if q_u.count() >1000, it not get all for you
var query = new Parse.Query("Vehicle");
query.matchesQuery("assignTo", q_u );
query.include("assignTo");
query.find().then(function(vehicles){
    //do what you want
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ChunTingLin but How this query proceed "var query = new Parse.Query("Vehicle"); query.near("location", userGeoPoint);" because here You are creating a query for Vehicle and use location for that  while location field is in _User class ?

Comment: And one more thing lets take a example I've 5 users in _User class  and  8 Vehicles and because one to one relationship 5 user have 5 vehicles , and it is possible that remaining 3 vehicles not assigned. So I want to get those only users that have vehicles with vehicles and users details within 10Km.

Comment: In your example, 5 user 8 vehicles, there must one user to map at least 2 vehicle. How to determine the vehicle of this user?

Comment: Last time, I think location is in Vehicle. Try this new one.